# getting Uncaught Error: Class 'SquareConnect\Configuration' not found after installing square ext in magento2

Tags: square, square-connect

I have installed square extension in magento to and enabled the module .
In the checkout page I got below error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SquareConnect\Configuration' not found in /home/...
```

Comment: Are you using the official Magento/Square integration found on Square's App marketplace (https://squareup.com/dashboard/apps)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .Got the solution , ``composer require square/connect``

Answer (score 2):

**Got the solution,**
I didn't executed the following command

```
composer require square/connect
```

After executing this, working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is June 2021 and I got the same error installing Square Module on Magento 2.3.

Following the latest extension docs V-1.9.0, it includes the following instructions on page 6.

https://marketplace.magento.com/media/catalog/product/square-module-squareup-omni-1-9-0-ce/user_guides.pdf

> 6-If you are installing fresh, version 1.0.0 or later:
>
> 1.the extension uses the official Square SDK: run command

```
composer require square/connect
```

> as well as

```
composer require square/square
```

> -If upgrading from an earlier version:
>
> 1.please first remove the previous SDK by running:

```
 composer remove adriansavuosf/squarepaymentssdk
```

> 2.then run command

```
composer require square/connect
```

> as well as

```
composer require square/square
```